# How do I get my Lexmark x4650 printer working?

Tags: printing, lexmark

I think that my printer stopped working with the switch to gnome 3 or unity. Yes I have tried 32 and 64 bit os's. [Here is the driver](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=en&page=product&productCode=LEXMARK_X4650&segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_US&frompage=null#1)

In order to actually install the driver, you need to extract it and then open up terminal and type sudo and then a space. Then drag the script into the terminal window. Here is what it said in the diver install window:

```
Extracting file: printdriver.te
Extracting file: lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb
Extracting file: launcher.c
Extracting file: launcherfallendohingy@Ubuntu-Inspiron-15R:~$ sudo '/home/fallendohingy/Downloads/lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh' 
[sudo] password for fallendohingy: 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing  nixstaller..............................................................
Collecting info for this system...
Operating system: linux
CPU Arch: x86_64
Warning: No installer for "x86_64" found, defaulting to x86...
TRACKING IDENT = 170209
cpu speed = 2394 MHz
ram size = 3762.69921875 MB
hd avail = 74348 MB

(gtk:17645): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory

(gtk:17645): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory

(gtk:17645): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory

(gtk:17645): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so

Extracting file: lsbrowser
Extracting file: lsusbdevice
Using dpkg installation
=============================
Execute: dpkg -i --force-architecture lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb > /tmp/selfgz17540/pkg/files/dpkg_msgs

=============================

=============================
Execute: rm lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb

=============================

=============================
Execute: /sbin/udevadm control --reload-rules

=============================

Successfully installed the .deb Lexmark drivers.
```

Comment: I removed the unity , gnome, and gnome3 tags as your question seems independent of these tags.

Comment: The Driver in which you want to install is not supported past Ubuntu 10.10 Per the web site it has listed: Operating Systems:  Ubuntu 9.04, Ubuntu 9.10, Ubuntu 10.04, Ubuntu 10.10, Debian 6.0, Linux Mint 10

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

1. `sudo apt-get install lzma`
2. `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
3. `tar -zxvf lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh.tar.gz`
4. `./lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.sh --noexec --target
   lexmark`
5. `tar xvf lexmark/instarchive_all --lzma`
6. `dpkg-deb -I lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb`
7. `mkdir raw-lexmark-archive`
8. `dpkg-deb -e lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb
   raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN`
9. `dpkg-deb -X lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb
   raw-lexmark-archive`
10. `cp raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control
     raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control.orig`
11. `sed "/^ $/d" raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control.orig >
     raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control`
12. `rm raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control.orig`
13. `cat raw-lexmark-archive/DEBIAN/control`
14. `dpkg-deb -b ./raw-lexmark-archive
     New-lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.deb`
15. `sudo dpkg -i New-lexmark-08z-series-driver-1.0-1.i386.deb.deb`

To remove the package run: `sudo dpkg -P lexmark-08z-series-driver:i386`

Answer (score 0):

Why not juts give a try to install the package like this:

```
gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /etc/gtk-2.0/gdk-pixbuf.loaders

or

touch /var/adm/SuSEconfig/run-gtk ; SuSEconfig
```

There is a bug for same reported here and seems it has not been solved till now.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdk-pixbuf/+bug/619003