# Help with lexmark printer X4650 on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: printing

So I have searched for hours and tried to download all kinds of drivers that should work. However everything that I try is either for older versions of ubuntu and dosn't work, is for 32 bit operating systems, or out of my technical abilities with linux. I just got it a couple days ago and although i am somewhat comfortable with command line, I hand jam a lot of router configs, the context and basic understanding of what or how im doing just isnt there yet.

Printer: Lexmark X4650
operating system: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
If a reference seems out of play I still mostly use the gui.

Additional Information Requests:

I have tried the following solutions and received the following errors. Note I get the same error for multiple solutions, you are not crazy.

1.
[Ubuntu 12.04 driver for Lexmark x4650](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207214/ubuntu-12-04-driver-for-lexmark-x4650)
result: Printer seems to install correctly. It shows up under printers, but when I print a test page, Under the printer properties, i get 3 statuses. 1 - Rendering page 1, 2) rendering complete, and 3 idle. The document just sits in the queue saying stopped and says the printer may not be connected. I physically verified that it is connected and powered.

2.
http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=901
Issues: Lexmark only offers 32 bit drivers.

3.
[How do I get my Lexmark x4650 printer working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108362/how-do-i-get-my-lexmark-x4650-printer-working)
Issues:
First, I think this is for 32bit, and after being directed to updated files in the first step, I was unable to advance to further steps because the file directory had to change.

4.
[How do I install drivers for a Lexmark X6675 Printer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130516/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-a-lexmark-x6675-printer/132000#132000)

#### Issues:

Same as first attempt:
Printer seems to install correctly. It shows up under printers, but when I print a test page, Under the printer properties, i get 3 statuses. 1 - Rendering page 1, 2) rendering complete, and 3 idle. The document just sits in the queue saying stopped and says the printer may not be connected. I physically verified that it is connected and powered.

Comment: Add exactly what you tried, so when we search we don't repeat the same steps you did. Also add the output of `lsusb` while the printer is connected.

Comment: Ok, I am looking up the references that I have tried now, Ill comment a list to this response in a couple minutes. What do you mean by add the output of lsusb? That I have not tried, I do not even know what that is or how to do it.

Comment: No, do not comment! Add that information in your question along with the results of each attempt. Also, do not just say "it didn't work", specify if there was any change or message.

Comment: Got it, I just noticed the edit, share, delete and flag options. Thanks for the super quick responses and any help you might be able to provide!